# Azure Databricks - writing to Az SQL table

Tags: python-3.x, azure-databricks

Am reading a .`parquet` (sourced from MySql) file into Databricks as a DataFrame and wanted to convert few column datatypes to SQL data types.

**Example**:

[image]

In this case want to cast columns `active` and `is_agent` to SQL DataType bit and write back to new data frame.

I want to loop through all columns in the data frame and apply above cast where source column data type is Byte.

How can this be achieved using Python.

Answer (score 0):

Ok got this one done as

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col 
from pyspark.sql.types import BooleanType

df = sourceDF.withColumn("active", col("active").cast(BooleanType())).withColumn("is_agent", col("active").cast(BooleanType()))
```

What I want is a function where I will pass DataFrame and loop through all column and and cast column of DataType Byte to BooleanType.